# how to pass image to Base Template/All Templates Django

Tags: python, django

from [this](https://dev.to/harveyhalwin/using-context-processor-in-django-to-create-dynamic-footer-45k4) tutorial I want to put some images in the navbar of my Django project.

I defined the `context_processors.py` like this:

```
from .models import Main_page

def get_labels_to_context(request):
    labels = Main_page.objects.all()
    
    return {
        'labels': labels,
    }
```

in the `Main_page` model I have 4 images that should be displayed in the navbar:

`models.py`:

```
class Main_page(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    
    label_services = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/pages/main_page/', blank=True)
    label_products = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/pages/main_page/', blank=True)
    label_support = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/pages/main_page/', blank=True)
    label_company = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/pages/main_page/', blank=True)
```

I added the context processor in the `settings.py` file.

In the template I try to show the images in this way:

```
<a href="#!" class="view overlay z-depth-1 p-0 mb-2">
    <img    src="{{ labels.label_services.url }}"
            class="img-fluid" 
            alt="Services label">
</a>
```

but the images are not being loaded!

any ideas?

Comment: So there will (always) be *one* `Main_page` record?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes.

Answer (score 0):

found what I was missing:

the `labels` is a dict and it should be treated as one!

```
{% for label in labels %}
{% if label.label_services %}
    <a href="#!" class="view overlay z-depth-1 p-0 mb-2">
        <img src="{{ label.label_services.url }}"
             class="img-fluid" alt="Services label">
    </a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```